# Find Index of all values of an array in another array and collect the value in that index from a third Array

Tags: iteration

I would like to find the index of matches from the descendentList in the parentIdList and then add the value which exists in that index from the idList to the descendentList and then once again check the parentIdList for the index of all the matching values.

I am essentially trying to create a looping structure which would result in looking like this:

Comment: Can you explain better what it is you're asking? Maybe an example of a run through?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but only if you can allow descendentList to be a Set. If not then I am not sure what the terminating condition would be, it would just keep adding the values of the same indexes over and over.  I think a Set is appropriate considering what you said in your comment above... "I would like to loop through this until no more matches are added to descendentList"

```
Set descendentList = [2]
def parentIdList = [0,1,2,3,2]
def idList = [1,2,3,4,5]

/** 
*   First: I would like to find the index of matches from the descendentList in the 
* parentIdList
*/
def findIndexMatches(Set descendentList, List parentIdList, List idList) {
  List indexes = []
  def size = descendentList.size()

  descendentList.each { descendent ->
    indexes.addAll(parentIdList.findIndexValues { it == descendent })
  }

  addExistingValuesToFromIdListToDecendentList(descendentList, idList, indexes)

  // Then once again check the parentIdList for the index of all the matching values.
  if(size != descendentList.size()) { // no more indexes were added to decendentList
    findIndexMatches(descendentList, parentIdList, idList)
  }
}

/**
* and then add the value which exists in that index from the
* idList to the descendentList 
*/
def addExistingValuesToFromIdListToDecendentList(Set descendentList, List idList, List indexes) {
  indexes.each {
    descendentList << idList[it as int]
  } 
}

findIndexMatches(descendentList, parentIdList, idList)
println descendentList // outputs [2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following seems to work - not written any tests though, so may fail with different use cases - just a simple, idiomatic recursive solution.

```
def descendentList = [2]
def parentIdList = [0,1,2,3,2]
def idList = [1,2,3,4,5]

def solve( List descendentList, List parentIdList, List idList ){ 
    List matchedIds = descendentList.inject( [] ){ result, desc ->
        result + idList[ parentIdList.findIndexValues{ it == desc } ] 
    }
    if ( matchedIds ){
        descendentList + solve( matchedIds, parentIdList, idList )
    } else {
        descendentList
    }
}

println solve( descendentList, parentIdList, idList )
```

Comment: Given this code, if you add a value to descendentList  so that descendentlList = [2,1] then the output is [2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4].  I think this is the same issue with allowing the same index to be added to the descendentList multiple times.

Comment: As per other response, indeed, does not state that the number can only be added once.  Can also be solved by adding unique() call (or checking at time of merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without recursion, using an iterator:

```
class DescendantIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final List<T> parents
    private List<T> output
    private final List<T> lookup
    private List<T> next

    DescendantIterator(List<T> output, List<T> parents, List<T> lookup) {
        this.output = output
        this.parents = parents
        this.lookup = lookup
    }

    boolean hasNext() { output }

    Integer next() {
        def ret = output.head()
        parents.findIndexValues { it == ret }.with { v ->
            if(v) { output += lookup[v] }
        }
        output = output.drop(1)
        ret
    }

    void remove() {}
}

def descendentList = [2]
def parentIdList = [0,1,2,3,2]
def idList = [1,2,3,4,5]

def values = new DescendantIterator<Integer>(descendentList, parentIdList, idList).collect()
```

After this, `values == [2, 3, 5, 4]`

Comment: I have the same concern here as stated in my comment for @rhinds solution. I guess you could simply call .unique() on it.

Comment: It depends on what they want the solution to be ;-)  They don't specify in the question as far as I can see

Comment: @dspano Might also be able to make use of `def lookups = parentIdList.indexed().groupBy { it.value }.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, idList[v.keySet()]] }`, but I can't currently find a clean place to use it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First build a map from parent id to all it's child ids.  Next find the results for the input and iterate over newly found results as long as there are no more.

```
def parentIdList = [0,1,2,3,2]
def idList = [1,2,3,4,5]

tree = [parentIdList, idList].transpose().groupBy{it[0]}.collectEntries{ [it.key, it.value*.get(1)] }

def childs(l) {
    l.collect{ tree.get(it) }.findAll().flatten().toSet()
}

def descendants(descendentList) {
    def newresults = childs(descendentList)
    def results = [].toSet() + descendentList
    while (newresults.size()) {
        results.addAll(newresults)
        newresults = childs(newresults) - results
    }
    return results
}

assert descendants([2]) == [2,3,4,5].toSet()
assert descendants([2,1]) == [1,2,3,4,5].toSet()
assert descendants([3]) == [3,4].toSet()
```